# Maintain ip link settings across reboot

Tags: networking, arch-linux, startup, network-interface

Every time I turn on my computer, I have to manually set `# ip link set wlp5s0 up` in order to use my wireless card. Is there a way to maintain this setting across reboots? So if I set the interface `up` it stays up until I turn it off.
I'd like to avoid using a 3rd-party network manager if at all possible. Using Arch.

Comment: There is possibly something strange in your configuration. Normally, the bootup process should enable the network interfaces. One way of ensuring network is up is `netctl ` in Arch (could hae been superseded by `systemd` now, though).

Comment: ip command is not persistent, you should use network manager... see https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_configuration You can use NetworkManager or systemd-networkd

Answer (score 0):

as root: `crontab -e`

```
@reboot ip link set wlp5s0 up
```

Comment: What package is `crontab` from? I'm getting a "command not found" on it.

Comment: Same here, any other equivalent apps?